# Is it possible to nullify the U.S. Constitution via amendment?

Tags: us-constitution

Is it possible to nullify all U.S. government by amending the constitution?

Comment: No, it would not be possible, because the amendment could not be enforced.

Comment: @user6726 how do you figure?

Comment: My comment preceded the edit, which substantially changed the question: but still, if the entirety of the constitution is "cancelled", then there is no court system with authority to determine what is allowed or disallowed, and thus no way to determine whether e.g. President Smith has a claimed power. The Constitution not only gives power, it *limits* power, so no action by the executive, military, or any other person would beyond the allowed. The entire pre-amendment Constitution could be imposed by fiat, and it would be perfectly "legal".

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, there are no restrictions on the scope of amendments to the US Constitution, and so, if properly proposed and ratified, and amendment could rewrite the entire document. But at that point the normal channels for amendments would likely have broken down.